# Autocad AEC property set formulas in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

When processing a DWG file that has property sets (an AEC feature) in Forge model derivative or in Forge design automation. If there are formulas in there, instead of the output of that formula, you get the plaintext of the formula itself. I think the formula language is (quasi-VBA / VBscript?) and looks like there are some context variables involved. Has anyone found a way around this?

edit:

[example dwg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZg6JNfcl8kZ2qhvdEegCLqXdGcr_WV5/view?usp=sharing)

This is the formula:

`RESULT="--"
On Error Resume Next
randomformula=[ObjectID]*[Area]
RESULT=randomformula`

and the line from model derivative metadata:

`"pset_test - Name": "RESULT=\"--\"\r\nOn Error Resume Next\r\nrandomformula=868384402720*4339762.18\r\nRESULT=randomformula",`

As you can see, we get back our original formula with just the values replaced. The same thing happens on design automation (no example here now). What I expected, is to get the same result I get in civil3d.

[image: result in civil3d]

Comment: Could you share more issue descriptions and some snapshots demonstrating what it is missing? If it cannot be posted publicly, please provide more details to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com. P.S. Please remove any personal data from anything you would like to send to us. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a known issue logged as `ACD-3668` by our engineering team and it's still under investigation now. Currently, there is no workaround for it.

As this issue requires exploration and possibly a modification to our API service, please make a note of this number for future reference. You are welcome to request an update on the status of this issue or to provide us with additional information at any time quoting this issue item number to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com.